# UK Visa Refusal - Please help

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I'm looking for help about my wife's UK Visa refusal.

There was an administrative error with the visa application, but I have no right to appeal against the decision. Therefore, I would like to change my Financial Declaration, as there must have been a mis-understanding when reading it.

I have changed the paragraph to the best I can, but would like a second opinion on how to improve the letter to reduce the likelyness of refusal again.

Please see letter below:

To Whom It May Concern,

RE; Declaration and explanation by Nattacha xxxxxxx of the source of cash saving for account 877-xxxxxxx and 052-xxxxxxx

As my visa application was been refused on 16th October 2019, based on your decision that I’ve stated the wrong bank account which showed no relation with my stated income, I would like to explain and clarify with the correct information below.

I, Nattacha xxxxxxxx, declare that;

the source of money in the Bangkok Bank (877-xxxxxxx) - Bank Statement was mainly earnt through employment, working for xxxxxxxxx, I have provided the maximum amount of pay slips as I can to support my declaration. Please find them on the following page.

The orange highlighted areas on the Bangkok Bank (877-xxxxxxxxx) – Bank Statement have been earnt from my monthly salary, working for xxxxxxxxx.

The source of savings in the Kasikorn Bank (052-xxxxxxx) – Bank Statement have been gathered from saving my salary, yearly bonus, and money that has been transferred from my husband, Mr. Xxxxxxx.

The blue highlighted areas on the Kasikorn Bank (052-xxxxxxx) – Bank Statement have been from where I have transferred my salary from my Bangkok Bank (877-xxxxxxxxx) – Bank Account to my Kasikorn Bank (052-xxxxxxxxx) – Bank Account.

As evidence, I have provided a letter of employment from my current employer xxxxxxxxx confirming my salary, attached with employment evidence too.

I will declare all of my salary and saving by using the highlight colours to make it easier for you.

- All of the orange highlighted areas in the Bangkok Bank - Bank account: 877-xxxxxxx are from my salary. The total amounts shown are my salary after paying tax and social insurance.
- All of the yellow highlighted areas are from Mr. Husband. I have explained in my introduction letter that we have been together for over 3 years and were living together when he was studying in Thailand and he transferred the money to my account each month to support me with rent and living expenses that were paid by credit card.
- All of the purple highlighted areas are money I have transferred to my mum to support my family each month.
- All of the Blue highlighted areas, in both savings accounts, are from myself transferring money from my salary account to my savings account.

The current balance of my Kasikorn Bank account is xxxxxxx Thai Baht which is the equivalent to xxxxxxx GBP, based on the exchange rate set on 20th September 2019. The current balance of my Bangkok Bank account is xxxxxxxx Thai Baht which is the equivalent to xxxxxx GBP, also based on the exchange rate set on 20th September 2019.

Please do not hesitate to contact me if any further details, or information is required.

Yours faithfully,

‐-------------------‐-------------------‐-------------------‐-------------------‐---------------

Please can anyone provide support on how the letter should be changed to make better and avoid another refusal?

Comment: I think you need to make some edits to your question as it's hard to understand what the issue is. Could you improve the title? Could you use " > " for the text you're quoting? Using "thanks" doesn't help here, please remove the "thanks" at the end of the question.

Comment: So, have a look at the [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit the question. I'll upvote after the edit.

Comment: Please attach a scan of your refusal notice, with all personal information blacked out. Without that we cannot have any idea if what you are writing will help. However in any case you are doing this wrong. You need to make a fresh application with the necessary evidence to show the officials these things.

Answer (score 3):

You have not given us much information to be sure, ***which is pretty much the crux of the problem***.

They didn't err. Your application was poor.

### Let your documents do the talking

There's an old adage in law.  If the law is with you, present the law. If evidence is with you, present evidence.  If nothing is with you, *just argue a lot*.

That's what your letter is.  You are arguing a lot.  In fact, you are relying on the **notion that ”the right combination of words can sway them”**.  You must break yourself of this habit, becaus it will never work.  I recommend changing the letter to two words.

> "Better documentation..."

The question of appealing pertains to payment.  What they mean is you can't get a review for free.  You can always apply again! However repeated applications which result in repeated refusals are highly suspicious.  So get it right the second time, or don't do it.

### Funds parking

The issue is that your bank statement does not prove your income.  Maybe someone loaned you some money to make your application look legitimate, which we cal "funds parking".  This is associated with scams to sneak people into the country on a legitimate visa, and then have them breach the terms of their visa by seeking illegal employment.  If you have been offered employ in the UK, this is fraudulent, and you should expect the people offering it do to other fraudulent things.

The UK wants to see bank statements with your name in it, which show periodic, regular deposits of this alleged income.  So show them a year or two worth of monthly bank statements with payments coming in, in the way that a paycheck would.

Some people in some parts of the world prefer to  live entirely in cash.  If this is the case, changing that habit will be essential to improve visa applications.

Comment: Pure cash living usually means distrust in government.  If you don't trust them, they have no reason to trust you.